# How to publish a review article on drugs in a reputed journal?

Tags: drugs

What are the things needed to publish a review article in a journal starting from scratch ? 
Is it possible if i am not associated to any institution ? 
How long does it take and what are all the guidelines that I should have in mind while writing an article ?

Comment: Why not try to write  some science articles for your local newspaper, many now have such columns,  rather than a full blown article, which as suggested in the answers is hard and time consuming even for an expert. That way you can get your name known and learn a lot  on the way.

Comment: You have no chance whatsoever to get a reputed journal to accept a review article. Doing research on your own is equally futile if you are just finishing your bachelor. Go and work on what you know, or should know. perfect grades in your final exams are *really* going to help you once this corona madness is over.

Comment: Better suited for Academia SE but as other said you are totally out of the track. It does not work like this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's outside of the scope of the site.

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind a review article is that it is an overview typically written by author(s) who is/are known to be experts in the field.  You need to be an expert because you are not merely publishing your own work, you are assessing and interpreting everyone else's work in this area. And it takes a lot of experience in the field to be able to do this -- to know what work is reliable, what work is questionable, what work is significant, and what work is of minor importance.  That's hard to do if you're starting from scratch.  If, on the other hand, you've been working in the field for 20 years, you know a lot of this to start.

For this reason, journals often invite known experts to write review articles.

The two exceptions I know of would be:

(1) a case in which a well-known expert is invited to write a review article, and then invites, say, a senior grad student to be a co-author.  But in this case, the senior expert is still providing guidance.  See, for instance:
https://www.asbmb.org/asbmb-today/careers/120111/writing-a-scientific-literature-review-article

(2) A review article written for a predatory journal.  If the journal is not legitimate, their standards are of course far lower! If you've been asked to write a review article for a predatory journal, or a predatory publisher, don't!  Here is a good list of predatory journals (though it may not be complete):

https://predatoryjournals.com/journals/

and of predatory publishers:

https://predatoryjournals.com/publishers/

You say you're interested in writing for a reputable journal.  Which one is it?  I would say that, before doing any work, you should contact them.  I expect, if it is a reputable journal, they would say the same thing I have.

In addition, is the journal in English?  If yes, then I can tell (even from your brief post) that you will need a good editor to clean up your English.

Comment: I am looking for ways to stregthen my profile in a short period for my masters application. I ve had a very limited research experience in my bachelors and I ve heard that students with publications have greater oppurtunity to get admitted. Are there any ways that you could suggest me to have any publication or to strenghthen my profile?

Comment: Usually the way students get published in peer-reviewed journals is by working for a research group, and being included on a paper as a coauthor.  Is there a university nearby where you could, say, do an internship in someone's lab?    The other option is to publish an opinion piece on a scientific subject of popular interest in, say, your local paper.   For instance, if you are interested in pharmaceuticals, you could publish an article about, say, their misuse, or their over-prescription, or about how doctors are being influenced by pharma companies to prescribe more expensive drugs, etc.

Comment: There are universities here  but due to the current situation of COVID-19, all I can do is with the computer and the application period starts in a month. I can think about articles in news papers. But i dont know why i couldnt lose the idea of having publication in a journal.

Comment: Having a publication as a bachelor just means that you were lucky, and/or had very good grades that helped you get into a project that resulted in a serious publication. It´s not going to impress anyone *alone*.

Answer (score 2):

As you stated you are a bachelors student and wish to apply for a masters. You would like to improve your academic profile. This is perfectly fine. It will be very hard to write a full fledged review at this stage and it will consume a lot of your time. A good review by a field expert may take six months just to write a draft and read more than 250 publications in detail. You can write for science *magazines* like Resonance which is published by the Indian Academy of Sciences. It does not have an impact factor but they do general publish science articles for public outreach. I did publish one article for fun there on making a "monochromator" in a shoebox (from my mother) long long time ago. I still occasionally read it. It is a good science magazine. Having one magazine article also indicates that you do have an inclination to write and compose essays.

What is your area which you think you are really good at? Can you address some math problems in a simplified way? Can you simplify something in chemistry? Do you know any good trick to balance chemical equations? There are matrix based methods which most people are not familiar with. Look at the topics in Resonance and probably write something with your teacher.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion about magazines. I am afraid that I am pretty much on my own if I am gonna publish such an article but I will be really glad if you could tell me the ways i could learn on learning to write an article by my own. Where do I start ?

Comment: You start from reading and reading and reading your topic of interest. A well-read person can write very well. Explore some issues of Resonance and see if you get the feel for the topics covered there.